# Ndepend find actual number of method usages

Tags: linq, ndepend, cqlinq

Let's say I have method `A.M1`.
It is called in `B.M2` 2 times and in `B.M3` 3 times.
I need to find all number of usages (like Resharper does through find usages interface). So the sum for method calls would be 5.

Following Query:

`from m in Methods 
where m.HasAttribute("specific attribute")
orderby m.MethodsCallingMe.Count() descending 
select new { m, m.MethodsCallingMe }`

gives me only 2 usages for method A.M1.

Could you please help me to find the usages number?

Comment: NDepend tells which methods is calling which methods, but it doesn't tell the number of time a particular method is calling another one.

Comment: SO the task is not achievable at all with NDepend?

Comment: No it is not achievable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult or impossible to do with NDepend. NDepends shows which methods are calling specified method and not count in this situation them and even not count them recursively or through call graph.

So try to use other techniques. By first of all, why you need such metric? Some kind of method rank?

Anyway a pretty simple way to achieve it, is using RegEx experssion. You can use also NDepend API or regex and ndepend api together. For example, get all method names from source code base using nDepend API and then using regex for each method name count matches except method definition itself.

Comment: NDepend API won't help neither since it shares the same code model than CQLinq (see my comment on question).

Comment: "and even not count them recursively or through call graph." concerning this, NDepend has plenty of facilities :)

Comment: "why you need such metric? Some kind of method rank?" NDepend has the metric IMethod.Rank  http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMethod~Rank.html